# Serial port ping functionality

Tags: c#, serial-port, detection

Does anyone know how do I check if a device is connected to a serial port? I need a sort of ping functionality so that I can ping the device and attempt to connect to it only if the ping succeeds. For instance if I don't have the COM cable plugged in, I can display the connection failed message much faster.

Comment: Do you have a specific device that you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I have a specific device that listens to the COM port but I want to determine when the cable is not plugged in the computer

Comment: How is the device wired?  If wired so that raising DTR or RTS raises DSR or CTS then you can use that to detect its presence.  If not send it a command and wait for response.

Comment: Thanks, I used the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class to open the connection and then I wrote some bytes. After that I tried to read one byte.(Writing and reading using the SerialPort class methods). From what I can tell the reading is only succesfull if a device is connected. (Note very important to call close and dispose on SerialPort object!!!)

Comment: If there was a device would it respond to the bytes you sent?  In other words was it a command that would cause data to be returned?

Comment: I used the SerialPort.Write instance method to send bytes to the device, and SerialPort.ReadByte instance method to read the bytes. This works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just isn't quite the same problem as having to use Ping to find if a server that's located a thousand miles away is online.  With serial ports you just look at the other end of the cable, you rarely have to walk more than a few feet.

There's also nothing similar to having a stateful connection like TCP.  All you can really do is look at the hardware handshake signals.  The SerialPort.DsrHolding gives you the state of the Data Set Ready signal.  A properly implemented serial device uses that signal to say that it is powered-on.  CtsHolding is an additional signal, it says that it is ready for you to send data.  They normally have to be both turned on before you consider sending anything.

These handshake signals are not always properly implemented.  You may well have a problem if the serial port is actually emulated by a BlueTooth or USB device driver for example.  Pretty common these days with very little consistency in how closely these drivers emulate a real serial port.  You'll have to try.